# change my code - divide the value of range and copy it in the cell below vba

Tags: vba, excel

I start with a sheet like this:

```
colB:
row1: 15
row2: (empty)
row3: (empty)
row4: 60
row5: (empty)
row6: 45
row7: 88
row8: (empty)
row9: 10
...
rowN: 56
```

I want to divide the value of non-empty cells (for example, 15 in row 1) into the number of following cells that are blank. This means that, after transformation, column B would look like this:

```
colB:
row1: 5
row2: 5
row3: 5
row4: 30
row5: 30
row6: 45
row7: 44
row8: 44
row9: 10
...
rowN: 56
```

I divide the number by the count of blanks + 1. For example (15 / 3) unless there are no blanks then divide by 1 (45 == 45).

This will do that up-to the last cell in B by anchoring a filled cell, looking at its vertical offsets then re-anchoring when one is not empty:

```
    Dim max As Long, i As Long, cell As Range        

    Set cell = Range("B1")        
    max = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        

    Do        
        i = i + 1        
        If (cell.Offset(i, 0).value <> "") Then        
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(i - 1, 0)).value = cell.value / i        
            Set cell = cell.Offset(i, 0)                
            i = 0        
        End If        

        If cell.Row = max Then Exit Sub        
    Loop
```

This line: `Range(cell, cell.Offset(i - 1, 0)).value = cell.value / i`  is wrong (type mismatch). VBA can't execute `cell.value / i`. How do I fix this?

Comment: I tried your code with your example input, and I can't reproduce the problem. If you want us to help, then you will have to give us a proper example; see http://www.sscce.org/.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett : I want to divide the value of filled cells into the number of empty cells (and then copy the values), like in the example above. But in my code I have an error at cell.value/i. I can't divide the value in this way. It's difficult to explain because the case is complicated.

Comment: What is the value of `i` when you get the error? Also check what is the value of `cell` when that error occurs. Hope you don't have a #NA or #DIV error in that cell which may be a result of a formula?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout : i is the counter of empty cells+1

Comment: I know that :) What is the value of it at the time of error?

Comment: :) How can I know? Sorry, I'm a beginner!

Comment: I get this error: type mismatch. I can't tell you more. :(

Comment: Can you upload your workbook to a free file sharing site and share the link here? Also, when you are replying to me, add `@` before my name so that I will get the alert

Comment: @Siddharth Rout , thank you. But I solved the problem. I found a string into my column...column B wasn't numeric so cannot be used in a mathematical expression. However, thank you very much.